# Adding style-like options to dialog buttons

Tags: jquery-ui, button, jquery-ui-dialog

As I said in a past post, I'm a JavaScript newbie, and now learned some JQuery.

### Briefing:

I need to create a dialog box that triggers when someone clicks on **Cancel**, and has (as **text** or **value**)"*Are you sure you want to exit?*", with two buttons: "*Yes, I want to leave*" and "*No, I want to stay on this page*". The redirect part from the "*I want to leave*" button will figure it out later.

Problem: I want to make the buttons to be **autoSizable** with the **width** option (in other words, `width:auto` and `height: (number)px`, but I can't figure it out :/

This is my code ->

```
 $(document).ready (function(){
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>');
    $(".selector").dialog({ modal:true });
    var $popUp = $('#btnCancel').one('click', function () {
        $dialog
        .html('All changes will not be saved')
        .dialog({
            title: 'Are you sure you want to exit?',
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            buttons: {

                "Yes, I want to leave": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                "No, I want to stay on this page": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    });
    $popUp.click(function () {
        $dialog.dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});
```

I tried changing the buttons part for this piece of code ->

```
    buttons: [
       { text: "Exit", 'class':'exit-button', resizable: true, click: function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } },
       { text: "Go back", 'class': 'go-back-button', resizable: true, click: function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } }
    ]
```

But in this last case, it creates two buttons with the value of "0" and "1", and have no onclick event.

What should I do?

Comment: Is something like this what you're looking for - http://jsfiddle.net/ckhG6/1/?

Comment: Um... no. I want to change the width and height, whether make it autoSizable (if possible) or set a determinated width/height value.

But thanks, you showed me something I didn't know it was possible :D

Comment: Change the height/width of the dialog, the buttons, or both?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention it on the comment. The buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the buttons an `id` when you create them you can style them with CSS, including giving them a `height` and `width`.

**Example** - http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/ckhG6/2/